# golang gorm many to many back reference

Tags: sql, go, many-to-many, go-gorm

I have this models, many-to-many, and I'd like to get all the Gifs that matches a list of Tags.

```
type Tag struct {
    ID      uint    `gorm:"primary_key" json:"id,omitempty"`
    Name    string  `gorm:"not null;unique" json:"name,omitempty"`
}
type Gif struct {
    ID      uint    `gorm:"primary_key" json:"id,omitempty"`
    Url     string `gorm:"not null;unique" json:"url,omitempty"`
    Tags    []Tag `gorm:"many2many:gif_tags;" json:"tags,omitempty"`
}
```

I prepared a playground [here](https://play.golang.org/p/xlwlCPmkNv).

If I have an array of Tags containing `tag1` and `tag2`, I'd like to get `gif1` and `gif2` in `&gifs`.

I read the documentation many times and found only the opposite of my question, i.e. fetching the tags for a given gif.

Do I need to change my models?
Is it possible to set up two Associations fields in a many-to-many relation?

Comment: Please make your playground workable and leave a comments near to a part you need to fix. Now it is full of errors.

Comment: The playground can't work because of the external imports. I updated the link. It is now functional if you run it on your computer. I added a comment where I needed help.

Comment: hmmm... looks like Go-GORM has no back reference support. So you should switch a models and declare reference in `Tag`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! So you think there's no way to put the same Association in both models ?

Answer (score 2):

So I found how to add back-reference.
I created two files in the same package containing the models, and added  Associations with the same join-table for the `many2many`.

`tag.go` :

```golang
type Tag struct {
    ID   uint   `gorm:"primary_key" json:"id,omitempty"`
    Name string `gorm:"not null;unique" json:"name,omitempty"`
    Gifs []Gif  `gorm:"many2many:gif_tags;" json:"gifs,omitempty"`
}
```

and `gif.go` :

```golang
type Gif struct {
    ID   uint   `gorm:"primary_key" json:"id,omitempty"`
    Url  string `gorm:"not null;unique" json:"url,omitempty"`
    Tags []Tag  `gorm:"many2many:gif_tags;" json:"tags,omitempty"`
}
```

They need to be in separate files.

Now I can access easily all the gifs matching a Tag and vice-versa.